# JSF -Set global font type for the excel sheet in JSF using HSSFFont in Apache POI

Tags: excel, jsf-2, primefaces, export-to-excel

I have an option to export the datatable to an excel sheet.
I am tryin to set the font type as "Calibri"  for all the cell in the sheet.
But the below code is assigning only the font type for the header not for the rest of the cells
**How can I able to set the font type globally for all the cell in the sheet ?**

```
  public void exportToXLS(Object document) {

        HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        wb.setSheetName(0, "report_lists"); // set sheet name
        sheet.shiftRows(0, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 4); // shifting the rows to
        HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(4);
        header.getCell(1).setCellValue("Test Group");
        header.getCell(2).setCellValue("Category");

        HSSFRow firstrow = sheet.getRow(0);
        firstrow.createCell(0).setCellValue("Actuals");

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss 'CDT'  yyyy ");
        Date date = new Date();
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5"));
        String reportDate = sdf.format(date);
        HSSFRow thirdrow = sheet.getRow(3);
        thirdrow.createCell(0).setCellValue(reportDate);

        HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        HSSFFont fontHeader = (HSSFFont) wb.createFont();
        fontHeader.setFontName("Calibri");
        cellStyle.setFont(fontHeader);
        System.out.println(" header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();::::"
                + header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());

        //only for changing font for header
        for (int i = 0; i < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
            HSSFCell cell = header.getCell(i);
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            // sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(i, cellStyle);

        }
        System.out.println("sheet.getLastRowNum():::" + sheet.getLastRowNum());
        for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); j++) {
            HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(j);
            if (row != null) {
                System.out.println(" j>>>" + j);
                // you can add sysout or debug here to check if all row passed
                // successfully
                for (int i = 0; i < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
                    HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        System.out.println(" i++" + i);
                        // you can add sysout or debug here to check if all cell
                        // passed successfully
                        HSSFCell celll = header.getCell(i);
                        celll.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Here is the screen shot of the excel:
[image]

Comment: How exactly is this a JSF problem? Are you implying that you don't face this problem when running the code in a Java application `main()` method instead in a JSF backing bean action method? Really...?

Comment: @Balue.Yes,the above code is in the backing bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit your code became like this :

```
public void exportToXLS(Object document) {

    HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    wb.setSheetName(0, "report_lists"); // set sheet name
    sheet.shiftRows(0, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 4); // shifting the rows to
    HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(4);
    header.getCell(1).setCellValue("Test Group");
    header.getCell(2).setCellValue("Category");

    HSSFRow firstrow = sheet.getRow(0);
    firstrow.createCell(0).setCellValue("Actuals");

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss 'CDT'  yyyy ");
    Date date = new Date();
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5"));
    String reportDate = sdf.format(date);
    HSSFRow thirdrow = sheet.getRow(3);
    thirdrow.createCell(0).setCellValue(reportDate);

    HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    HSSFFont fontHeader = (HSSFFont) wb.createFont();
    fontHeader.setFontName("Calibri");
    cellStyle.setFont(fontHeader);
    System.out.println(" header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();::::"
            + header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());

    //only for changing font for header
    //for (int i = 0; i < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
    //    HSSFCell cell = header.getCell(i);
    //    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        // sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(i, cellStyle);

    //} you dont need this because the code bellow will change all style including header

    System.out.println("sheet.getLastRowNum():::" + sheet.getLastRowNum());
    for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); j++) {
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(j);
        if (row != null) {
            System.out.println(" j>>>" + j);
            // you can add sysout or debug here to check if all row passed
            // successfully
            for (int i = 0; i < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
                HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i);
                if (cell != null) {
                    System.out.println(" i++" + i);
                    //HSSFCell celll = header.getCell(i); <<you also don't need this, this is the root of your problem, you choose to change header only instead of already declares cell
                    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: @Ang.I tried both of these code nothing seems to work form me. for for(int i = 0; i < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) { HSSFCell cell = header.getCell(i); cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle); } for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) { CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle(); // modify your style here style.setFont(fontHeader); sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(i, cellStyle); }.If possible please add the code for style in your above answer.

Comment: Yes, I got an exception "file error:some data have been lost" when i opened the file, after that the sheet got opened but font type dod not got changed except the header part.Do you mind trying the above code in your machine and let me know your valuable suggestions ?

Comment: lets try the simple one first, if you try to change that default code of yours from `cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);` to `sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(i,style);` what will happen?

Comment: I tried the one above I got the first four rows formatted with the expected font the rest of the rows were not respoding.If you look at the code above I was shifting the the rows to fourth row creating empty row in the first four rows.So now the code  for (int i = 0; i < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
HSSFCell cell = header.getCell(i);cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(i, cellStyle);} is considering the first four rows and impying the changes not for the rest of the other rows.Please let me know the next step.Do you mind try running in in your machine ?

Comment: like i said before, try to remove that `cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle)`, change with `sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(i, cellStyle)` not add both of them. I currently away from my workspace, can't run that now.

Comment: Its applying for only at the top 4 rows not for the rest or the rows.I tried only this method sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(i, cellStyle).

Comment: AS per this comment given for the method sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(i, cellStyle).This method Sets the default column style for a given column.POI will only apply this style to new cells added to the sheet,which means I am creating the fours rows at the top where i shifted the acutals rows.

Comment: Ah that explain everything, sorry i forgot that you edited those xls. Not making new one. i will edit my answer for you to use the second solution then.

Comment: Thank you so much .Can't wait to see the solution.Keep me posted !!

Comment: Just finish editing. if that still doesn't work, tel me about the result of that `sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` and your actual row count in your excel.

Comment: If you look at the question at the top.I have already mentioned the code for (int i = 0; i < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) { .It was applying only for the header.Not for the rest.Since, you asked the sop is "27".

Comment: not `getPhysicalNumberOfCells()` but `getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` is the problem if you only get 1 row formated.

Comment: yes, its formatting only one row.like i mentioned above.

Comment: and i ask about this in my above comment "if that still doesn't work, tel me about the result of that sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() and your actual row count in your excel"

Comment: RESULT OF THAT sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()  IS 27.And yes the datatable has 27 columns.I already mentioned this above.

Comment: and your actual row? edit your question with your updated code, i curious if there is something wrong with the looping.

Comment: Ang,I just updated my question with my latest code that i tried so far.You can have a sample sheet having random values and test it with the given code and let me know your response.My actual row is from start to end i need to format the sheet with the specific font that i mentioned in the question

Comment: thats because you use `header.getCell(i);` haha.. you should use `row.getCell(i);` :D

Comment: why did you override that row.getCell(i) with header.getCell(i)(line 2 from last line)? when you create new variable celll? cell should be enough.

Comment: "header." object is nothing but the actual row and in that row I am taking the cell which is header.getCell(i).Well, that works for me.Also the line 2 from last line is just a try I gave we can remove it.But that too did not worked for me.

Comment: your "header" object is always `sheet.getRow(4)` when row is `sheet.getRow(j)` thats different.

Comment: i update my answer, you just need to copy and replace your code. btw, where did you write that result? didn't you need `wb.write(outputStream);` at the end of that method of yours?

Comment: ANG IT WORKS FOR ME !! .THE LAST POINT YOU SAID WAS WORKING FOR ME WHICH IS THE LAST FOR LOOP.I REMOVED header.getCell(i)(line 2 from last line) AND IT WORKED FOR ME.YOU ARE THE MAN :).THANK YOU SO MUCH